# One line initialization of class who's values are set with a method instead of the constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have a class `Test`:

```
class Test {
public:
  int a;

  Test();
  int set(int a);
};

Test::Test() {}

int Test::set(int a) {
  this->a = a;
  return a;
}
```

An instance of this class would be able to be initialized with a value like this (of course):

```
Test t;
t.set(10);
```

But is there a way to do this in one line? The following code **doesn't** work.

```
Test t.set(10);
```

---

#### When would I want to do this?

I'm using a game development library - SFML - and to apply a texture to a shape I need to pass a reference to a `Texture` instance, like this:

```
Texture texture;
texture.loadFromFile("mud.png");

rect.setTexture(&texture);
```

And I want to create a class with some static constants defining some textures, which I could then use elsewhere.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when `texture` goes out of scope and gets destroyed?

Comment: `Test t; t.set(10);` is one line

Comment: Also `Test t = Test().set(10);`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik when `texture` goes out of scope the texture wouldn't work. That's what I expect.

Comment: And what do you expect to happen when `rect`, whatever that is, continues to use that pointer?

Comment: SFML __still__ haven't discovered existence of constructors in C++? I thought they overhauled that some time ago.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik When `rect` continues to use the pointer, the library I'm using renders the rectangle without a texture (solid colour.) How is this relevant?

Comment: It's relevant because after `Texture` gets destroyed, the pointer to it, inside `rect`, becomes a dangling pointer, and referencing it results in undefined behavior and a likely crash (unless explicit steps are taken to handle this situation, which were not mentioned in the question, thusly presuming not to apply, here).

Comment: AFAIK, SFML handles the undefined pointer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it's irrelevant to the question, and probably not a problem in this case. You're just nitpicking one of millions of things that could be done wrong later in the code which is pointless to the discussion

Answer (score 2):

You can create a helper make function:

```
auto make_texture_from_file(const std::string& filename) -> Texture
{
    Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromFile(filename); 
    return texture;
}
```

Comment: The biggest issue for this is if the `Texture` class isn't movable, then a copy is necessary.  Obviously, the example `Test` class is movable, but that might not be the case with other classes.  Of course, RVO might fix that either way.

Comment: Other than what Graznarak said, are there any other problems of using this method? It seems like a good method

Comment: @Graznarak NRVO will most likely kick in.

Comment: @bolov I agree, but it might not in debug mode or if he is using a less reputable compiler than GCC, Clang, or VC++.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether it is what you have tried to achieve, but you said *"...a class with some static constants defining some textures..."*. So as far as I understood you want a some way to initialize your static textures and it has to be done outside of the class. Consequently, initialization has to be **a one single expression** (probably that's what you've meant by "in one line").

So here is my proposal (just an example):

*Texture.h*

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

struct Texture
{
    std::string fileName;
    std::string filter;
    std::string wrap;

    Texture& LoadFromFile(const std::string& _fileName)
    {
        fileName = _fileName;
        return *this;
    }

    Texture& Filter(const std::string& _filter)
    {
        filter = _filter;
        return *this;
    }
    Texture& Wrap(const std::string& _wrap)
    {
        wrap = _wrap;
        return *this;
    }
    Texture& Finalize()
    {
        // Some final strokes.
        // Omit this if not needed.
        return *this;
    }
};
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Texture.h"

struct Textures
{
    static const Texture bricks;
    static const Texture wood;
};

const Texture Textures::bricks = Texture()
        .LoadFromFile("bricks.png")
        .Filter("GL_LINEAR")
        .Wrap("GL_REPEAT")
        .Finalize();

const Texture Textures::wood = Texture()
        .LoadFromFile("wood.png")
        .Filter("GL_NEAREST")
        .Wrap("GL_REPEAT")
        .Finalize();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Image: "  <<  Textures::wood.fileName     << std::endl
              << "Filter: " <<  Textures::wood.filter       << std::endl
              << "Wrap: "   <<  Textures::wood.wrap         << std::endl
                                                            << std::endl
              << "Image: "  <<  Textures::bricks.fileName   << std::endl
              << "Filter: " <<  Textures::bricks.filter     << std::endl
              << "Wrap: "   <<  Textures::bricks.wrap       << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Image: wood.png
Filter: GL_NEAREST
Wrap: GL_REPEAT

Image: bricks.png
Filter: GL_LINEAR
Wrap: GL_REPEAT
```

If I understood the question wrong or made any mistake, please, let me know in comments.

**Edit:** if a single-time texture copy (which should occur here) hits your load performance and Texture class has a move constructor, you can just add `std::move(Texture()...);`

```
const Texture Textures::bricks = std::move(Texture()
        .LoadFromFile("bricks.png")
        .Finalize());
```

or `Finalize()` can be sightly changed to return rvalue reference, then `std::move(...);` mentioned higher is not needed - `Texture` will be moved automatically:

```
Texture&& Finalize()
{
    return std::move(*this);
}
```

Comment: Whilst the previous answer did actually solve my problem, this answer is better and I would have used it, had it been posted earlier.

Comment: Still, I hope it will be helpful for someone)

Comment: It'll likely be useful to me in the future, as I can see myself writing similar programs after this